# SugarCRM CE smarty error after upgrade

Tags: sugarcrm

I recently upgraded our SugarCRM CE form 5.x to 6.2.6.  I had some uphill experience but I overcome everything except one issue.

The following error appears in the "Email Address" area on Contact, Opportunity and other similar pages.

> Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource:
>   "include/SugarFields/Fields/Base/detailViewFunction.tpl" in
>   /home/campusre/public_html/sugar/include/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on
>   line 1095

I did a search on SugarCRM forum and I found only one similar thread that was old and not answered. I also contacted our hosting company to check if this problem is related with the file or folder permission but they confirmed that it is not the problem in this case.

I am a developer but didn't do any SugarCRM and Smarty development before. I am investigating the code by my self but without success so far.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> unable to read resource: include/SugarFields/Fields/Base/detailViewFunction.tpl

This usually means that incorrect permissions are set on this file or that the file doesn't exist. However, in this case it looks like a casing issue. The file is actual camel case and named DetailViewFunction.tpl. It looks like you are running into a case-sensitive issue. My initial guess is that it is due to an old module or piece of code from 5.x.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Yes, the file exists and the name is camel case DetailViewFunction.tpl.  I thought of that before and I tried to rename the file in detailViewFunction.tpl to mach the case  but it didn't work also.  Do you have some advice how to investigate this issue further if there is a problem in some old module like you said ?

Comment: Search the code for detailView with a lowercase d for the offending code.

Comment: I tried to search the whole code for detailView with lowercase d, but I couldn't see some obvious problem somewhere. As I mentioned the warning appears in contact details table in "Email Address" area instead of the contact's email address.  What template shows that part of the page or what module can possibly contain this old code?